# How can sfdx force:community:create be used to setup a Community in Continuous Integration?

Tags: community, salesforcedx, lightning-community, continuous-integration

These SFDX [community commands](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_community.htm) are available, but on my first try just running these commands:

```
sfdx force:community:create --name Portal --templatename 'My Template' --urlpathprefix portal
sfdx force:community:publish --name Portal
```

the "create" output was:

```
=== Create Community Result
Your community is being created. We’re creating your community.
Run sfdx force:org:open -p _ui/networks/setup/SetupNetworksPage
to view a list of your communities,
and to confirm when this community is ready.
```

quickly followed by the "publish" output:

```
ERROR running force:community:publish: The Portal community doesn't exist.
Verify the community name and try publishing it again.
```

If you have a strategy for waiting until the community is created (that is better than just an arbitrary sleep) in an automated script to address this problem, please share it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Community creation process is asynchronous, and the time required varies significantly depending on what template you select.

In CumulusCI's `create_community` task (which calls the same endpoint as SFDX, I believe; it's the new Connect API resources introduced in Summer '19), I poll the `connect/communities` endpoint with a GET request to find a list of all Communities, and I just wait for the name of the Community I asked to create to appear there.

In Python, it's something like this, where `sf` is a `simple_salesforce` instance:

```
while True:
    community_list = sf.restful("connect/communities")["communities"]
    communities = {c["name"]: c for c in community_list}
    if target_community_name in communities:
        self.logger.info(
            "Community {} created".format(communities[target_community_name]["id"])
        )
        break
```

Polling based on the URL path prefix would also work fine. `connect/communities` returns a list of community records in the key `communities`. The endpoints are documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/features_communities.htm), and particularly you want the `GET` resource under [Community List](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_communities_list.htm).

You'd want to insert some kind of sleep in each loop iteration to keep the polling reasonable.

Comment: Thanks David, makes sense though disappointing that there is no direct SDFX mechanism for this.

Comment: we've created a couple plugins which has been a smooth process, you might think about creating your own synchronous version of the command that creates the community and then polls for it to be created ...

Comment: Thanks @RalphCallaway, that is a maybe. Presently we've put most of our effort in this direction https://github.com/claimvantage/sfdx-jenkins-shared-library (though perhaps we should move to CumulusCI instead).